# Can someone help me with this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left(4x^2+3xy+y^2\right)dx+\left(4y^2+3xy+x^2\right)dy=0$$

Comment: **Hint:** Let $y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x$

Comment: I put this question on hold for the benefit of this site. Please note that questions which are just a problem statement are negatively received on this site, and will likely be closed. I provided a hint for you, but for next time, please provide us with your thoughts on the problem and show us everything you have tried. That way, we do not repeat any information you already know, and we can write answers in the appropriate level.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** This is a [first-order homogeneous ODE](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/first/homogeneous/homogeneous.html) since it can be written in the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4x^2+3xy+y^2}{x^2+3xy+4y^2}=-\frac{4+3\frac{y}{x}+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}{1+3\frac{y}{x}+4\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}$$

In general, these types can be solved by the substitution $y=vx$, which by the product rule implies that $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$. This will reduce your differential equation to a [separable](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx) one which you can solve for $v(x)$.